# Chrome font-face not loading local font

Tags: c#, css, font-face, google-webfonts

I am running into an odd issue.  Using the webfont link through google's webfonts api works just fine and loads the font, however... The app i'm creating is local only, so having any kind of overhead connecting to the internet is noticeable when rendering the fonts for the first time, plus no font would be loaded if there is no internet connection.

```
@font-face {
font-family: Pt Sans;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
src: url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/ptsans/v4/jduSEW07_j4sIG_ERxiq4Q.woff);
}
```

The above is the working code.

```
@font-face {
font-family: Pt Sans;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
src: url(fonts/ptsans.woff);
}
```

This works when running directly from the browser locally, however i'm using a framework which embeds the chrome webview into my C# application, called CefSharp. The difference is, i'm simulating a link to a site, rather then loading the pages directly. It would be as if I created my own http:// link to the font, like the webfont.

If I open up Chromes dev tools > resources tab > fonts and click the locally loaded font, it shows a default font, however if I click the font loaded through google's api, it renders the correct font.

What is the google api sending to the browser that i'm not? I've tried numerous mimeTypes to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know font-face cross-domain policy? You could try to send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` in fonts' http headers.